# var from shared libraries, switch to Jenkinsfile stage - No such property: value1 for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

Again with the old groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value1 for class: groovy.lang.Binding ...

I keep running into these things, this time with a shared library running a switch statement.

Any ideas on how to read the variables (value1, env) that are set in the library (that echoes the variables just fine) to the Jenkinsfile (that doesn't get the variables)?

I'm expecting: jfile values are "some-dev-value" and dev

Jenkinsfile:

```
@Library('piplinesharedlib') _
pipeline {
  agent any
    stages {
        stage('env setting by branch') {
            steps {
                branchSelector("${GIT_BRANCH}")
                echo "jfile values are ${value1} and ${env}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

shared library:

```
def call(String GIT_BRANCH) {
    echo "gitbranch is ${GIT_BRANCH}"
    def version = "1.0"

    def values = readProperties file: "${env.WORKSPACE}\\values.groovy"
    //def value1 = ''

    switch(GIT_BRANCH) {
        case "develop":
            env = "dev"
            echo "setting env to ${env}"
            value1 = values['DevValueloadedFromReasources']
            break
        case ["master", "Feature*".toString()]:
            env = "prod"
            echo "setting env to ${env}"
            value1 = values['ProdValueloadedFromReasources']
            break
        case "Feature*":
            env = "dev"
            echo "setting env to ${env}"
            value1 = values['FeatureValueloadedFromReasources']
            break
        default:
            value1 = "nothin"
            break
    }
        echo "The values for this env are ${value1} and ${env}"
    }
return this
```

output:

```
...
gitbranch is develop
[Pipeline] readProperties
[Pipeline] echo
setting env to dev
[Pipeline] echo
The values for this env are "some-dev-value" and dev
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value1 for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:270)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:289)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:293)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:269)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:269)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(ModelInterpreter.groovy:137)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:682)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:417)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(ModelInterpreter.groovy:415)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.executeSingleStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:681)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:280)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:566)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.toolsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:565)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:465)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:464)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:269)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:503)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:502)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:268)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:315)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(ModelInterpreter.groovy:607)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inDeclarativeAgent(ModelInterpreter.groovy:606)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(ModelInterpreter.groovy:378)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.stageInput(ModelInterpreter.groovy:377)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:311)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(ModelInterpreter.groovy:634)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.inWrappers(ModelInterpreter.groovy:633)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.evaluateStage(ModelInterpreter.groovy:251)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor378.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:282)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:270)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bashing my head on the wall... as it turns out, simply calling ${branchSelector.value1} works.

```
    stage('env setting by branch') {
        steps {
            branchSelector("${GIT_BRANCH}")
            echo "jfile values are ${branchSelector.value1} and ${branchSelector.env}"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a global:

```
def value1 = null // or maybe simply `value1 = null` if this doesn't work

@Library('piplinesharedlib') _

pipeline {
```

Answer (score 1):

to solve your problem at the first create a groovy file with name sharedLib.groovy and define two global variables "value1" and "env" then annotate them with @Field with default value. change value of these two variables in your method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import groovy.transform.Field

@Field value1 = ''
@Field env = ''
def myMethod(String GIT_BRANCH) {
    echo "gitbranch is ${GIT_BRANCH}"
    def version = "1.0"

    //def values = readProperties file: "${env.WORKSPACE}\\values.groovy"

    //def value1 = ''

    switch(GIT_BRANCH) {
        case "develop":
            env = "dev"
            echo "setting env to ${env}"
            value1 ="1"
            break
        case ["master", "Feature*".toString()]:
            env = "prod"
            echo "setting env to ${env}"
            value1 ="2"
            break
        case "Feature*":
            env = "dev"
            echo "setting env to ${env}"
            value1 = "3"
            break
        default:
            value1 = "nothin"
            break
    }
        echo "The values for this env are ${value1} and ${env}"
    }
```

then use thefollowing code

```
@Library("piplinesharedlib") _
pipeline {
  agent {label "coreop-pasargad-246"}
    stages {
        stage('env setting by branch') {
            steps {
            script{
                sharedLib.myMethod("${GIT_BRANCH}");

                //branchSelector("${GIT_BRANCH}")
                echo "jfile values are ${sharedLib.value1} and ${sharedLib.env}"
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```